# No UID when using Django admin page to create objects

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

So I have created a custom User model and a common model as base for all other models that adds a created_by field.

If I now use the Django admin page to create an object(just for testing) then I get the error that the UID is Null.

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Creates and saves a new User"""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email address")
        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email), **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
 
        return user
 
    def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        """creates and saves a new superuser"""
        user = self.create_user(email, password)
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
 
        return user

class CommonModel(models.Model):
    """Common fields that are shared among other models"""
 
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        editable=False,
        related_name="+",
    )
 
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """Custom user model that supports using email instead of username"""
 
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
 
    objects = UserManager()
 
    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
```

I get this error:

IntegrityError at /admin/core/tenant/add/
null value in column "created_by_id" of relation "core_tenant" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (3, 2022-05-20 15:11:27.755389+00, 2022-05-20 15:11:27.755413+00, test1234, blablka, null, null, null, null).
Request Method:            POST
Request URL:     http://127.0.0.1:8900/admin/core/tenant/add/
Django Version: 4.0.4
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:
null value in column "created_by_id" of relation "core_tenant" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (3, 2022-05-20 15:11:27.755389+00, 2022-05-20 15:11:27.755413+00, test1234, blablka, null, null, null, null).
Exception Location:         /py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py, line 89, in _execute
Python Executable:         /py/bin/python
Python Version: 3.9.9
Python Path:
['/fwmodule',
'/usr/local/lib/python39.zip',
'/usr/local/lib/python3.9',
'/usr/local/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
'/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
Server time:       Fri, 20 May 2022 15:11:27 +0000

So it seems like when using the admin page to create objects the UID cannot be resolved.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show me the `UserModel` you defined?

Comment: @David Lu just added the user Model

Comment: Can you show me the error?

Comment: @David Lu just added the error message as well. As you can see the UserID value like 3 others  are Null. (there is a updated_by, created_at and updated_at as well)

Comment: Can you show me the `UserAdmin` class?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to define some fields in that class.

Comment: I have not defined an extra admin user class, my User Class uses the Django AbstractBaseUser class. When I create the superuser with manage.py my class seems to be used as it asked me for the email and not a name.